# How to route request for static file to cshtml file in asp.net web pages

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, webmatrix

I am busy developing a website using asp.net web pages. As part of the seo process i have created a robots.cshml file that will output the text content of a robots.txt file based on the page structure of the site. Is there any kind of mechanism that i can use to route all requests for robots.txt to the dynamic robots.cshtml file to handle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other way around, route all your robots.txt request to robots.cshtml. Something like this, with IIS Url Rewriting:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Rewrite to dynamic robots">
            <match url="^robots.txt$" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="robots.cshtml" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Thanks,  I was originally thinking along the lines of Routes.MapPageRoute or something and I completely missed the simplest solution.